# Adding to the start of a collection in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Is there anyway to add a value to the start off a collection by position instead of by index.

For example:

```
Series.add(0) = "New Value"
```

Using the .add function it only looks to add to the end of the collection and I was hoping there was a way to add to the start.

Michael

Answer (score 4):

You can use the optional Before and After arguments to maintain an ordered collection of objects. The item to be added is placed in the collection before or after the item identified by the Before or After argument, respectively. **For example, setting Before equal to 1 inserts an item at the beginning of the collection, because Collection objects are 1-based.**

So just use Before:=1 to add at the start of the collection, for example:

```
Collection.Add Item:=something, Before:=1
```

Found in the link shared by Doug Coats

Answer (score 3):

See [Visual Basic for Application reference about Collection.Add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265006%28v=vs.60%29.aspx)

I guess both links are useful

https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/f26wd2e5(v=vs.100).aspx

It looks like you can use before or after to adjust add position.

the syntax for that is : object.Add(Item, Key [, {Before | After}])

So if you enter a number in either of those slots (its an index reference), it will place it before/after. Note you cannot use both before and after.

Comment: A bit more than just a link would be useful :)

Comment: this should help alot :)